# Cannot use @page in IE, Safari (CSS)

Tags: css

I want to use `@page` in CSS to customize print page.

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size:auto;   
        margin-top:2.5in;
        margin-left:-2.5in;
    }
    .body {
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        position:relative;
        -webkit-transform:scale(0.5);
     }
}
```

It's work in Chrome but not work in Internet Explorer and Safari. So, how can I use it in there, if not, which one I can change `@page`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530841(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @TusharGupta: i don't know, Apple supports it for Safari?